# How to customize existing PrimeFaces themes?

Tags: css, primefaces, themes

I am using PrimeFaces theme switcher in my project using PrimeFaces all-theme jar. However some of the themes font, alignments or colors are not appropriate. How can we customize it? Say, there is one Afternoon theme and I want to customize input-text field or calendar background, so how can I customize it?

I tried unzipping the jar and look into the source CSS file, but not able to track the input-text field.

Comment: you have to post your code so we can understand for customisation.

Comment: I think instead of posting your code, learning ccs basics an learn how to use a browser developer tool would be more efficient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)